# Avoid double nested elements while using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My stored procedure creates an XML (by taking all the inputs from the consumer) like the following:

```
<Event>
    <DataSource>Test</DataSource>
    <Name>SomeTable.Created</Name>
    <Context>SomeTable</Context>
    <ContextKey>
        <SomeFieldId>999</SomeFieldId>
        <SomeOtherFieldId>777</SomeOtherFieldId>
    </ContextKey>
</Event>
```

The `ContextKey` is an XML input that needs to be given by the consumer in this format:

```
<SomeFieldId>999</SomeFieldId>
```

(Then my stored procedure creates the above XML for me..)

But I have an important question here:

What if the consumer sends in the `ContextKey` xml like this:

```
   <ContextKey>
      <SomeFieldId>999</SomeFieldId>
    </ContextKey>
```

I don't want duplicates with TWO `ContextKey` elements... My stored procedure needs to omit the duplicated input and just create the "Event" xml with only one `ContextKey` element ..

Could someone suggest how I can put a condition so that even if the consumer sends in the XML inclusive of the attribute itself, my code should actually create the `Event` XML by only creating one element for `ContextKey`??

Hope my question is elaborated enough. Appreciate all your help! This is of much importance.

For more clarity:

This is how my XML PATH looks like inside my stored procedure:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = (SELECT DataSource = @DataSource, 
                   Name = @EventName,
                   Context = @EventContext,
                   ContextKey = @EventContextKey
            FOR XML PATH('Event')) 

SET @Payload = @xml
```

Comment: Hi, is this still open? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, this whole approach smells a bit...

But - to give you a hint - you could do it like this

Here I define two alternatives of your parameters, one with and one without the enclosing elements:

```
DECLARE @prm1 XML='<SomeField>999</SomeField><SomeOtherField>000</SomeOtherField>';
DECLARE @prm2 XML='<ContextKey><SomeField>999</SomeField><SomeOtherField>000</SomeOtherField></ContextKey>';
```

Here I to the same process to both: If there is an Element `ContextKey` then take its internals else the parameter *as is*...

```
SET @prm1=CASE WHEN @prm1.exist('//ContextKey')=1 THEN @prm1.query('//ContextKey/*') ELSE @prm1 END;
SET @prm2=CASE WHEN @prm2.exist('//ContextKey')=1 THEN @prm2.query('//ContextKey/*') ELSE @prm2 END;
```

Now your query

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
SET @xml = (SELECT DataSource = 'MyDataSource', 
                   Name = 'MyEventName',
                   Context = 'MyContext',
                   ContextKey1 = @prm1,
                   ContextKey2 = @prm2
            FOR XML PATH('Event'));

SELECT @xml;
```

The result. You see, that both parameter were handled the same way and show up in the same way - even it they were different in the beginning...

```
<Event>
  <DataSource>MyDataSource</DataSource>
  <Name>MyEventName</Name>
  <Context>MyContext</Context>
  <ContextKey1>
    <SomeField>999</SomeField>
    <SomeOtherField>000</SomeOtherField>
  </ContextKey1>
  <ContextKey2>
    <SomeField>999</SomeField>
    <SomeOtherField>000</SomeOtherField>
  </ContextKey2>
</Event>
```